# Linq many-to-many, GroupJoin or SelectMany

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've been stuck on a `linq query` for a very long time, and just can't figure out how to solve it.

[I have this many-to-many relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W0GQ.jpg)

Course class:

```
public class Course : BaseEntity
{
    public Course()
    {
        CourseCollections = new HashSet<CourseCollection>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CourseCollection> CourseCollections { get; set; }
}
```

CourseCollection class:

```
public class CourseCollection
{
    public CourseCollection()
    {
        Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

What i want to do is to, by supplying a `collectionId` and a `companyId`, return a single `CourseCollection` object, with all belonging courses to the collection inside the list.

For instance, if i have 3 courses belonging to Collection 1, and 2 courses belonging to collection 2, i want to be able to query Collection 1 and return the collection with the 3 courses inside the `ICollection`.

**What i've tried so far:**

```
var group = _context.CourseCollections.GroupJoin(_context.Courses,
            collection => collection.Id,
            course => course.CompanyId,
            (collection, courses) =>
                new
                {
                    Id = collection.Id,
                    CompanyId = collection.CompanyId,
                    Name = collection.Name,
                    Courses = courses
                }
        ).AsQueryable();
```

But this doesn't work - (and it shouldn't work as the Courses table is not queried correctly). I just can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: Neither `GroupJoin` nor `SelectMany` is needed. Just query the `_context.CourseCollections` (e.g. `.Where(cc => cc.Id == collectionId && cc.CompanyId == companyId)`) and EF lazy loading will do the rest for you. Or use eager loading to get everything with a single database query.

Comment: I tried that, but just got returned an object without any courses: `{
        "Company": null,
        "Courses": [],
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "Collection 1",
        "CompanyId": 1
    }`

Comment: May be the lazy loading is disabled. Use the second option (eager loading) then, e.g. `_context.CourseCollections.Include(cc => cc.Courses).Where(...)`

Comment: Doesn't a `collectionId` uniquely identify a single `CourseCollection`? What is the primary key for `CourseCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Projection to anonymous type using "select" (works well with eager or lazy loading):

```
var group = _context.CourseCollections
                    .Select(x => new {x.Id, 
                                      x.CompanyId, 
                                      x.Name, 
                                      x.Courses})
                    .ToList();
```